# Combine columns and get count SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Forgive me, I'm still learning but am in need of some assistance. Some of what I’ve done is an amalgam of previous questions but I can’t find quite what I’m looking for.

I have a table with 30 columns of data, let’s call it table1.  Every two columns are actually a set of the same type of data that have meaning together and singly.  For example col1 with col2, is say a set of names.

Like this:

```
1              Jim         Jeff
2              Mike        Ben
3              Mike        Mike
4              Peter       Jeff
5              Jeff        Jim
6              etc         etc
```

The remaining 28 columns aren't important at this point. I want to return a single list of the unique names in col1 AND col2 along with their counts in total from both columns. Here’s what I have and it seems to work to a point but there is a problem with the return.

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1

UNION

SELECT col2, COUNT(*) 
FROM table2
GROUP BY col2
```

The problem is, when col1 has a name in it that is also in col2 it will return two counts. For example, if I had 6 different names, a total of 100 times, 50 in each column I might see something like this returned with the above query.

```
Jim         4
Jim        13
Jeff        8
Jeff       19
Mike       11
Mike       34
Ben         4
Brian       2
Peter       5
```

Obviously, Jim, Jeff and Mike appear in both columns and Ben, Brian and Peter appear in only one (It seems to me that it doesn’t matter which one).

What I need returned is:

```
Jim         17
Jeff        27
Mike        45
Ben          4
Brian        2
Peter        5
```

I tried putting a subquery in GROUP BY to force what is returned by a union without the count (forgive me, I don’t know much SQL, I'm just making assumptions by what little I understand of the language), meaning:

```
GROUP BY (SELECT col1 FROM table1 UNION SELECT col2 FROM table2)
```

but I guess I’m making silly assumptions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get the list of all names, then do a count based on that.

```
;WITH Names AS
(
    SELECT col1 AS [Name]
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT col2 AS [Name]
    FROM table2
)
SELECT [Name], COUNT(*)
FROM Names
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Comment: That gives me a count of 1 for each name.

Comment: Oops, sorry @Dan, that `UNION` should have been a `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This. Is. Beautiful!  Thank you so much.  I apologize for my ignorance on the subject.  Still learning what all these things mean.

Comment: It still works without the semicolon.  Is there a particular reason or meaning of it?

Comment: The semicolon is the statement terminator in SQL Server. It's mostly not required, with a few exceptions. When writing CTEs, you have to explicitly use one after the statement previous to the CTE `;WITH...`. If you have no statements before the CTE, then you might not need the semicolon. Best preactice is to always use one at the beginning of your CTE block. Check here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Comment: Any chance adding a frequency column is easy.  I’ve been trying all day and can’t seem to get it to work.  I was thinking about adding to the last query “, COUNT(*)/SUM(...) AS [Frequency]”.  But no matter what I put in sum it won’t give me a sum of that NAME column.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a subquery or CTE. If you're still having trouble with calculating the frequency, you should probably create a new question for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!